# Manipulating table data in Java after reading .txt file using Scanner or Buffer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to manipulate row and column data in a tilde delimited table contained in a .txt file in Java. I have successfully scanned/read the data but am not sure how to manipulate it to mirror the actions of relational algebra and then writes the output to a new .txt file as a tilde delimited table like the original so that it can then be read by another method like project(). For example I would like to create a `restrict()` method that will restrict the output to only Toyotas so the main body of a driver program might look like this:

```
//restrict the cars table to toyotas producing a table named toyotas    
Algebra.Restrict("cars","MAKE='Toyota'","toyotas");  

//project just three columns from the toyotas table producing a table named answer    
Algebra.Project("Toyotas","Make,Model,Price","answer");  

//display the contents of the answer table    
Algebra.Display("answer");
```

output would be:

```
MAKE MODEL PRICE
---------------- 
Toyota Camry 18000    
Toyota Tacoma 19000    
Toyota Highlander 35000
```

**Input from cars.txt**

```
MAKE~MODEL~TYPE~PRICE

Toyota~Camry~Sedan~18000

Toyota~Tacoma~Truck~19000

Ford~Mustang~Sport~21000

Chevrolet~Corvette~Sport~48000

Ford~F150~Truck~25000

Toyota~Highlander~SUV~35000
```

**Using the following code for algebra.Restrict("Ford", "", "Truck");:**

```
   public void Restrict(String a, String b, String c )throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    {
        Scanner x = null;
        try
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File("cars.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        while (x.hasNext())
        {
            String str[] = x.next().split("~");
            arr.add(str);
        }

        for (String[] column : arr)
        {
            if (column[0].equals(a))
            {System.out.println(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);

                // save table to disk     
                PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("RestrictTable.txt");
                outputfile.print(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);
                outputfile.close(); 

            }


        }
        for (String[] column : arr)
        {
            if (column[1].equals(b))
            {System.out.println(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);

                // save table to disk     
                PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("RestrictTable.txt");
                outputfile.print(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);
                outputfile.close(); 

            }



        }
        for (String[] column : arr)
        {
            if (column[2].equals(c))
            {System.out.println(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);

                // save table to disk     
                PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("RestrictTable.txt");
                outputfile.print(column[0] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[2]);
                outputfile.close(); 

            }


        }
                        System.out.println("NEW TABLE SAVE TO DISK");




    }


    }
    public void Project(String a)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        {
        Scanner x = null;
        try
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File("cars.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        while (x.hasNext())
        {
            String str[] = x.next().split("~");
            arr.add(str);
        }

        for (String[] car : arr)
        {
            if (car[0].equals(a))
            {
                System.out.println(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2]);

                // save table to disk     
                PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter("ProjectTable.txt");
                outputfile.print(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2]);
                outputfile.close(); 

            }

        }
                        System.out.println("NEW TABLE SAVED TO DISK / ProjectTable.txt");




    }


    }
```

**Output I get:**

```
Ford Mustang Sport
Ford F150 Truck
Toyota Tacoma Truck
Ford F150 Truck
NEW TABLE SAVE TO DISK
```

**desired output**

```
MAKE~MODEL~TYPE
Ford~F150~Truck
NEW TABLE SAVE TO DISK
```

**or at the very least**

```
Ford F150 Truck
NEW TABLE SAVE TO DISK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Read the data into a variable and create a data object. The simplest is an array and list, better if you create `car class` and create a key value pairing but for simplicity here is a potential solution.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cars
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner x = null;
        try
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File("cars.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        while (x.hasNext())
        {
            String str[] = x.next().split("~");
            arr.add(str);
        }

        for (String[] car : arr)
        {
            if (car[0].equals("Toyota"))
            {
                System.out.println(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2] + " " + car[3]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Toyota Camry Sedan 18000
Toyota Tacoma Truck 19000
Toyota Highlander SUV 35000
```

I did this in 5minutes but you can easily use it as a template to make methods `restrict`. Template would be similar to.

```
private boolean restrictBy (String make){
  if make.equals("Totota") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
File outFile = new File ("output.txt");
FileWriter fWriter = null;
try { fWriter = new FileWriter (outFile); }
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter (fWriter);
for (String[] car : arr)
{
    if (restrictBy(car, "Ford" , "", "Truck"))
    {
        System.out.println(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2] + " " + car[3]);
        pWriter.println(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2] + " " + car[3]);
    }
}
pWriter.close();
```

and the method restrictBy

```
private static boolean restrictBy (String[] car, String make, String model, String type) {
    boolean filtered = true;
    if (make.length() > 0 && !car[0].equals(make))
    {
        filtered = false;
    }
    if (model.length() > 0 && !car[1].equals(model))
    {
        filtered = false;
    }
    if (type.length() > 0 && !car[2].equals(type))
    {
        filtered = false;
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: NICE! thanks, thats exactly what I was trying to figure out how to get the data into variables. So for project i guess it would be the same like if i only wanted to project the first 3 coulmns

Comment: @SteveRogers yup, you can pick and choose what you want to display. `car[   ]` 0-3 are all the identifiers to a car, you keep everything in variables but you can decide what to print out. If this answered your question please mark it as the answer. I could really use the points since i'm new :)

Comment: @SteveRogers `System.out.println(car[0] + " " + car[1] + " " + car[2] + " " + car[3]);` is all 3 columns, just remove the ones you don't want. Say you only want column 2 and 4. Such that output would be for example `Camry 18000` then `System.out.println(car[1] + " " + car[3]);` Remember that array's always start at 0 :)

Comment: --- also if I want to eventually use this for any make would i just repeat the if statement for each make? for example i may want to write restrict('Toyota'); or restrict('Ford'); or restrict('Truck'); to only show trucks   -- and why would i need to use the boolean restrictBy() to return true or false when i want to return table data

Comment: i think i got it figured out i just need to write the results (new table esentially) to a .txt file

Comment: @SteveRogers yup, the condition was toyota in this case. But if you wanted to do it for other's you could do exactly as you mentioned. Instead of `system.out.println` you can use any of java's standard output methods such as `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedwriter_write_string.htm`, lots of things to choose from.

Comment: 2 issues  1 - i got it to write but it only writes the last row of the resulting table instead of the whole table and 2 - my restrict("Ford","","Truck") should return only Ford F150 Truck but returns all Fords, then all F150's, then all Trucks in same table. I will update my code up top. thanks!

Comment: @SteveRogers I don't see any code modifications in your post, i guess you figured it out?

Comment: @SteveRogers Not sure what you're trying to achieve, i added some code to my initial reply. Maybe that's what you meant?

Comment: basically, when I run the restrict() I want to restrict it to only Ford or only Toyota or maybe even just Trucks or Sedans but for now let just say Toyotas. then a new table will be written to a txt file names Toyota -then the project() method will project only the first 3 columns of the new table that restrict() just wrote. Then i could maybe write a method to display() the final results - even if i couldn't accomplish all of that i would settle for restrict("Ford","","Truck") returning only cars that are both Fords and Trucks instead of returning all Fords & all Trucks like it currently is

Comment: but its ok no worries you have been a huge help, thanks!

Comment: @SteveRogers the above addition i made accomplishes that for you :) Not a problem, when you have a chance just upvote it if you don't mind ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use can use streams (requires Java 8). This is a mapping of relational algebra operations that you mentioned to methods of `Stream`:

- Restrict: `filter`
- Project: `map`
- Display: `collect`

You have to be aware of the disadvantages of your approach in comparison to a relational database management system:

- Requires a lot of memory in case of much data (does not scale well)
- No query optimization
- No indexes
- No transactions
- No constraints

Comment: thanks a lot, but lets say for example (forget relational algebra for a second) if I just wanted to mimic a query SELECT * FROM table WHERE make ='Toyota'; - what would be the best route to accomplish that. Also if you have links to any tutorials or youtube videos that'd be awesome. Thanks again, i am an SQL guy & sort fo new to Java and for some reason our professor wants us to write a Java program out of the blue

Comment: Use can apply a sequence of filter, map and collect to do this. More information can be found here for example: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/74.Java8.Streams-Overview/74.Java8.Streams-Overview.html. It shouldn't be difficult to find more information by googling "Java streams".